# If $2^n-1$ is prime, then n is prime - proof involving the Mersenne primes by counterexample

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $2^n-1$ be prime. Suppose that $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_s$ is composite. Then we have $2^{p_1p_2\cdots p_s}-1$; call it $k$. If $k$ is prime, then its only divisors are $k$ and $1$. But consider the case

$$ 2^6-1=2^{2\cdot3}-1=64-1=63=3\cdot3\cdot7$$

Clearly, $k=2^n-1$ is not prime, which contradicts the hypothesis. Does it suffice to conclude at this point that if $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime? Or is it necessary to invoke the algebraic identity

$$ a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}$$

And show generally that

$$ 2^{p_1p_2\cdots p_s}-1=(2^{p_1}-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p_2\cdots p_s -1}a^kb^{p_2\cdots p_s-1-k} \qquad\Rightarrow \qquad {(2^{p_1}-1) | (2^{p_1p_2\cdots p_s}-1)} $$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319963/if-2n-1-is-prime-from-some-integer-n-prove-that-n-must-also-be-prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the case when $n = 6$ only shows that  $2^n - 1$ is not prime *for all* composite $n$ (i.e. at least one of $2^n - 1$ is composite).

However it does not show that $2^n - 1$ is not prime *for every* composite $n$ (i.e. all of $2^n - 1$ are composite), which is what is required in the contrapositive form of the question.

By invoking the stated algebraic identity you essentially show that $2^n - 1$ is not prime *for every* composite $n$, which will complete the proof.