# Showing that $a = 2^{1264504 }- 1$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

Is there a simple way to show this? Quite new to these kind of proofs. I tried writing down the powers:
$2^0 - 1 = -1 \\ 2^1 - 1 = 1 \\ 2^2 - 1 = 3 \\ 2^3 - 1 = 7 \\ 2^4 - 1 = 15 \\ 2^5 - 1 = 31$
...
I'm not sure what to do from here...

Comment: More broadly, $2^n-1$ prime $\implies n$ prime.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319963/if-2n-1-is-prime-from-some-integer-n-prove-that-n-must-also-be-prime) for example.

Comment: $2^n-1$ for $n>0$ is not even, so perhaps try divisibility by $3$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice that you are raising 2 to an even power, and remember that
$$
a^2-1 = (a+1)(a-1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is divisible by $3$ since $2^2\equiv 1\mod3$,
so
$$2^{1264504}-1=(2^2)^{632252}-1\equiv 1^{632252}-1=0\mod3.$$