# Prove contrapositive of a statement after proving its converse. (If $n$ is prime then $2^n-1$ is also prime)

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

I have been given the following problem:

> Let *n* > 1 be a positive integer. Let *P* be the following statement:
>
> If *n* is a prime number then $2^n - 1$ is a prime number
>
> Write down the converse of the statement P. Is it always true? Justify your answer.

I have solved this part by using a proof by contradiction, in the same way that is shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319963/if-2n-1-is-prime-from-some-integer-n-prove-that-n-must-also-be-prime). However, this problem is followed up with the following:

> Write down the *contrapositive* of the statement P.
>
> Is it always true? Justify your answer.

From my understanding the contrapositive of P is:

**If $2^n-1$ is not prime, then *n* is not prime**

What I'm struggling with is how to go about proving this. Could I just use the same method as the previous part of the question (again, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319963/if-2n-1-is-prime-from-some-integer-n-prove-that-n-must-also-be-prime))? Or would I have to get the contrapositive of the contrapositive (resulting back in P) and prove that in some way?

Comment: Contrapositive or converse?

Comment: $2^{11}-1$ is composite.

Comment: The contrapositive is always equivalent to, and hence of the truth value as, the original proposition, but the converse is another matter. In this case, $P$ is false and of true converse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse statement to statement (A) below:

> (A) If $n$ is a prime number, then $2^n-1$ is a prime number.

is statement (B):

> (B) If $2^n-1$ is a prime number, then $n$ is a prime number.

Likwise, statement (A) is the converse to statement (B).

Statement (A) is false but statement (B) is true.

To see that (A) is false, note that $2047=2^{11}-1$ as per lulu's comment, and $11$ is prime but $2047$ is infact not. So (A) [and thus the contrapositive to (A)] is not true.

On the other hand, (B) is true. We show this by working with the contrapositive of (B), which we will write as (B$'$):

> (B$'$) If $n$ is not prime, then $2^n-1$ is not prime.

To establish (B$'$), first suppose that $n$ is not prime. Then write $n=pq$ where both $p$ and $q$ are integers at least $2$. Then $$2^n-1=2^{pq}-1$$ $$=$$ $$(1+2^q+2^{2q}+\ldots +2^{(p-1)q})(2^p-1),$$ and both
$1+2^q+\ldots + 2^{(p-1)q}$ and $2^p-1$ are at least $2$ [actually at least $3$], because $p$ and $q$ are both integers at least $2$, and so $2^p$, $2^{(p-1)q}$ are each at least $2^2=4$. So $2^n-1$ is a product of $2$ integers each at least $2$, so $n$ is not prime. Thus (B$'$) is true.

As (B) is precisely the contrapositive of (B$'$) and (B$'$) is true, it follows that (B) must be true as well.

Comment: Yes, this formula can not produce primes

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean converse. We can use a proof by exhaustion to prove the converse and disprove the contrapositive. As @lulu pointed out in the comments, $2^{11}-1=2047$, which is composite, but $11$ is still prime, which means that $2^n-1$ does not need to be prime for $n$ to be prime. I found another example as well:  $n=23$. I hope this answers your question. Don't hesitate to ask any questions in the comment section below.

Comment: I believe the question asked the OP to work w the converse.

Comment: The converse is "If $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime". Giving a prime integer $n$ s.t. $2^n-1$ is not prime does not prove nor disprove this.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to make another point. Note that, there is no simple computable and useful algebraic expression or function $f(n)$, such that if $n$ is prime, then $f(n)$ is also a prime number. Unfortunately, such a simple formula currently doesn't exist, as far as I know.