# I need help with the following proof if $2^{n}-1$ is prime, show that $n$ is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Thanks in advance for any help,

I was struggling to understand the factoring at the end of this proof and was hoping someone could give me some help with it.

The problem is as follows,

> If $2^{n} -1$ is prime, show that $n$ is prime.
>
> Suppose $n$ is prime false so that $n$ is not a prime,
> say $n=ab$ where $a\ge2$ and $b\ge2$ both
> integers.
>
> If we write $2^{a}=x$, then $2^{n}=2^{ab}=(2^{a})^{b}=x^{b}$. Hence $$
> > 2^{n}-1=x^{b}-1=(x-1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}+...+x^2+x+1). $$
>
> As $x\ge4$, this factors $2^{n}-1$ into smaller positive integers, a
> contradiction.

To be precise, I don't understand where $x\ge4$ is coming from and how $x^{b}-1=(x-1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}+...+x^2+x+1). $

Thanks again,

Comment: This question has been answered on here before:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440035/prove-contrapositive-of-a-statement-after-proving-its-converse-if-n-is-prime/4440056#4440056

See the answer from myself Mike

Comment: To answer your specific question, $x=2^a$ for some integer $a \ge 2$ which gives $x \ge 2^2=4$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate--see thread in comments. Also it appears the OP's question is answered

Comment: Great. Excuse the cross post.

Comment: It looks like OP is specifically wondering about the factorization itself., and why $x\ge 4$. For the latter, consider that having either $a=1$ or $b=1$ leads to trivial answers. Hence $x=ab \ge 4$. For the first part, the factorization $$x^b - 1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+ \cdots +x^2+x+1)$$ is relatively well-known... basically it's one of those tricks to memorize and keep in the back of your brain. (Note that it doesn't always work for $x^n+1$)

Comment: Hey, thanks, @EricSnyder

Comment: There's an easier route than this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove contrapositive of a statement after proving its converse. (If $n$ is prime then $2^n-1$ is also prime)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440035/prove-contrapositive-of-a-statement-after-proving-its-converse-if-n-is-prime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question : if$x=2^a$ with $2\leq a$ then $x$ is a power of two strictly greater than 2, so at least is equal to 4 i.e. $4\leq x$.

For the second question just make the usual polinomial division and use an inductive argument.